# Get different background color on fullcalendar agendaDay

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I need to ask, I want to change background color in `agendaDay` based on time. So background color in `agendaDay` changed every 15 minutes. So if user see the fullcalendar on 9pm, background color on `agendaDay` before 9pm is have different background color that after 9pm.

I tried insert time manually to array and then loop it, but the result is I changed all background color in `agendaDay`. Do you know how to fix this ?

Here's the code

```
  eventRender: function(events, element) {
            var time = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
            var minTime = "05:00:00";
            var maxTime = "24:30:00";
            var arr = ['05:00:00', '05:15:00','05:30:00', '05:45:00', '06:00:00', '06:15:00','06:30:00', '06:45:00',           '07:00:00', '07:15:00','07:30:00', '07:45:00', '08:00:00', '08:15:00','08:30:00', '08:45:00', '09:00:00', '09:15:00','09:30:00', '09:45:00', '10:00:00',];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(time<= arr[i])
                {
                    $(".fc-time-grid .fc-slats td").css('background-color', 'green');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".fc-time-grid .fc-slats td").css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `$(".fc-time-grid .fc-slats td")` selects all the TDs without any filtering. Actually if you examine the HTML, there are some TRs which have `data-time` attributes. You need to select based on those.

Comment: P.S. using "eventRender" for this makes no sense because this code will run repeatedly, once for each event you load into your calendar. There's really no need for that. Using the "viewRender" callback would be more suitable. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender